# Can xml-schema be used to define meta data (using xerces)?

Tags: xml, xsd, xerces

say I have an xml-file. Now what my program does depends on the "element". Is it possible for xml schemas to define the action that the program should do? Ie is the following possible:

```
 <xs:element name="test" hidden=true action=myActionOnTestElement>
```

And then when xerces' parser reads elements of name "test" it also stores the action & that this element is "hidden". If this is impossible with xerces, is it possible at all with XML parsers?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to define an element with attributes, like this

```
<test hidden="true" action="myActionOnTestElement"/>
```

then you should use `<xs:attribute>` element in your schema. This method is possible for all XML parsers that support W3C XML Schemas. The spec for this schema element is here http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/#cAttribute_Declarations

Comment: No this is exactly what I do NOT want. I do not want to change the xml file - I want a way to define my program how to handle xml files. What to do when ti reads tag YZ or XY.

Comment: Well the processing and interpretation of XML data depends solely on the application that consumes that XML. Parser reads the XML code and passes the structure to your application. Schemas are for defining a certain allowed structure and binding data types to values. Neither parsers or schemas define the action that the programs should do. XML tags themselves never have a real functional meaning until it is created by your app that interprets the data.

Comment: well I'm looking into an efficient (clean) way to "define" and "structure" the behaviour in my application. But I guess this method is a "no".